# Combobox SelectedItem doesn't show

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have the following `Combobox`:

```
<ComboBox Name="cb_Zeitraum" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Zeitraum}" IsEnabled="{Binding TimespanAvailable}" SelectedItem="{Binding Zeit}" SelectedIndex="0" Style="{StaticResource requiredFieldValidationStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="26"/>
```

My Problem is when I select an `Item` it isn't displayed inside the `Combobox`, it just stays blank. But the the `Item` is selected, just not shown. It just stopped working. I have reversed all the changes I made after it stopped working but that didn't help.

```
<!-- Required Fields -->
<Style x:Key="requiredFieldValidationStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="TextBox.BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBox.ToolTip" Value="Eine Eingabe wird benötigt."/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Picture:**
[image: Combobox Problem]

**Declaration:**

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _zeitraum = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Zeitraum
    {
        get { return _zeitraum; }
        set { _zeitraum = value; }
    }

private string _zeit;
    public string Zeit
    {
        get { return _zeit; }
        set
        {
            _zeit = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Zeit");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you set `SelectedIndex="0"`?

Comment: So that the first Item is selected by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting rid of `SelectedIndex="0"` and do it via `SelectedItem="{Binding Zeit}"`.

Do

```
Zeit = Zeitraum.FirstOrDefault();
```

in your CodeBehind or ViewModel (what ever you’re using).

**Edit:**

If you look closely at your picture, you can see the top left corner of the V. Try setting the `Width` of your `ComboBox` to a higher value.

Comment: It works in the way that inside Zeit is the correct `string`. But as you can see in the Picture I added to my original Post, it isn't displayed in the `Combobox` itself, just in the `Dropdown`. No matter what I select, the `Combobox` stays blank.

Comment: I have added the declaration for both to the Original Post.

Comment: try setting the `Width` of the `ComboBox` to a higher Value. (100 or so)

Comment: Alright, it worked. After looking trough some Code, it appeared Visual Studio decided to add the Width by itself. But still thank you. I just deleted the Width Property completly so it adjust to the Item length.

Comment: If you look closely at your picture, you can see the top left corner of the `V`. Yeah… the happens sometimes if you unintentional click something.

Answer (score 0):

What type is `Zeit`? If it's an object (opposed to a value type) you may want to set the `DisplayMemberPath` property on the combobox so that it knows to display that member when the item is selected.

Comment: I have added the declaration for both to the Original Post.

Comment: Ah. Looking closer, you set the Width of the Combobox to 26. That's not very wide at all. Consider using "Auto" or HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" instead - I suspect that you haven't left enough space for the content to be displayed.